# Freezable Data Context in Behavior WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datacontext, attachedbehaviors

I am creating a behavior for Keypress as I have a specific requirement for triggering a command when a key is pressed in an application. I am not using the WPF KeyBinding as I have several user controls with all having their respective ViewModels. I wrote the below behavior which works fine :-

```C#
    public class WindowKeyPressBehavior : Behavior<Control>
    {
        #region Public Properties.

        public KeyCommandCollection KeyCommandCollection
        {
            get => (KeyCommandCollection)GetValue(KeyCommandCollectionProperty);
            set => SetValue(KeyCommandCollectionProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty KeyCommandCollectionProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("KeyCommandCollection",
                typeof(KeyCommandCollection),
                typeof(WindowKeyPressBehavior),
                new PropertyMetadata(null));

        #endregion

        #region Constructors.

        public WindowKeyPressBehavior()
        {
            KeyCommandCollection = new KeyCommandCollection();
        }

        #endregion

        #region Protected Method Declarations.

        protected override void OnAttached()
        {

            base.OnAttached();

            WeakEventManager<Control, RoutedEventArgs>.RemoveHandler(AssociatedObject, nameof(AssociatedObject.Loaded), AssociatedObject_Loaded);
            WeakEventManager<Control, RoutedEventArgs>.AddHandler(AssociatedObject, nameof(AssociatedObject.Loaded), AssociatedObject_Loaded);

            WeakEventManager<Control, RoutedEventArgs>.RemoveHandler(AssociatedObject, nameof(AssociatedObject.Unloaded), AssociatedObject_Unloaded);
            WeakEventManager<Control, RoutedEventArgs>.AddHandler(AssociatedObject, nameof(AssociatedObject.Unloaded), AssociatedObject_Unloaded);
        }

        #endregion

        #region Private Method Declarations.

        private void AssociatedObject_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            WeakEventManager<Window, KeyEventArgs>.RemoveHandler(Application.Current.MainWindow, nameof(Application.Current.MainWindow.PreviewKeyDown), MainWindow_PreviewKeyDown);
            WeakEventManager<Window, KeyEventArgs>.AddHandler(Application.Current.MainWindow, nameof(Application.Current.MainWindow.PreviewKeyDown), MainWindow_PreviewKeyDown);
            LoadDataContexts();
        }

        private void AssociatedObject_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            UnloadDataContexts();
            WeakEventManager<Window, KeyEventArgs>.RemoveHandler(Application.Current.MainWindow, nameof(Application.Current.MainWindow.PreviewKeyDown), MainWindow_PreviewKeyDown);
        }

        private void MainWindow_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (KeyCommandCollection == null || !KeyCommandCollection.Any(x => x.Key == e.Key))
            {
                return;
            }

            try
            {
                IEnumerable<KeyElement> keyCommands = KeyCommandCollection.Where(x => x.Key == e.Key);
                foreach (KeyElement keyCommand in keyCommands)
                {
                    // Run it in an asynchronous way as CanExecute/Execute can be time consuming in certain cases
                    // preventing the next command to run.
                    Application.Current?.Dispatcher?.Invoke(() =>
                    {
                        KeyElement command = keyCommand;
                        // If parameterized command is available execute it.
                        if (command.ParameterizedCommand?.CanExecute(command.CommandParameter) == true)
                        {
                            command.ParameterizedCommand.Execute(command.CommandParameter);
                        }
                        // If non-parameterized command is available, execute it.
                        else if (command.Command?.CanExecute() == true)
                        {
                            command.Command.Execute();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception)
            {
               //TODO : Log Any Errors.
            }
        }

        private void LoadDataContexts()
        {
            foreach (KeyElement keyElement in KeyCommandCollection.Where(x => x?.DataContext == null))
            {
                keyElement.DataContext = AssociatedObject?.DataContext;
            }
        }

        private void UnloadDataContexts()
        {
            foreach (KeyElement keyElement in KeyCommandCollection.Where(x => x?.DataContext != null))
            {
                keyElement.DataContext = null;
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

The `KeyElement` class inherits from `FrameworkElement` as below

```C#
    public class KeyElement : FrameworkElement
        {
            public Key Key
            {
                get => (Key)GetValue(KeyProperty);
                set => SetValue(KeyProperty, value);
            }
    
            public static readonly DependencyProperty KeyProperty =
                DependencyProperty.Register(
                    "Key",
                    typeof(Key),
                    typeof(KeyElement),
                    new PropertyMetadata(System.Windows.Input.Key.None));
    
            public DelegateCommand Command
            {
                get => (DelegateCommand)GetValue(CommandProperty);
                set => SetValue(CommandProperty, value);
            }
    
            public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandProperty =
                DependencyProperty.Register(
                    "Command",
                    typeof(DelegateCommand),
                    typeof(KeyElement),
                    new PropertyMetadata(null));
    
            public DelegateCommand<object> ParameterizedCommand
            {
                get => (DelegateCommand<object>)GetValue(ParameterizedCommandProperty);
                set => SetValue(ParameterizedCommandProperty, value);
            }
    
            public static readonly DependencyProperty ParameterizedCommandProperty =
                DependencyProperty.Register(
                    "ParameterizedCommand",
                    typeof(DelegateCommand<object>),
                    typeof(KeyElement),
                    new PropertyMetadata(null));
    
            public object CommandParameter
            {
                get => GetValue(CommandParameterProperty);
                set => SetValue(CommandParameterProperty, value);
            }
    
            public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandParameterProperty =
                DependencyProperty.Register(
                    "CommandParameter",
                    typeof(object),
                    typeof(KeyElement),
                    new PropertyMetadata(null));
    
            public override string ToString()
            {
                return $"Key : {Key}";
            }
        }
    
        /// <summary>
        /// Collection of Key-Commands.
        /// </summary>
        public class KeyCommandCollection : ObservableCollection<KeyElement>
        {
        }
```

My XAML file is as below :-

```XML
    <UserControl
        x:Class="Test.Views.LanguageSelectionPage"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
        xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:behaviors="clr-namespace:Test.Behaviors;assembly=Test.UI.Core"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
        d:DesignHeight="1024"
        d:DesignWidth="1280">
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <behaviors:WindowKeyPressBehavior>
                <behaviors:WindowKeyPressBehavior.KeyCommandCollection>
                    <behaviors:KeyElement
                        Key="{Binding KioskWorkflow.PrmConfiguration.UpKey}"
                        ParameterizedCommand="{Binding SwitchCommand}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding KioskWorkflow.PrmConfiguration.UpKey}" />
                    <behaviors:KeyElement
                        Key="{Binding KioskWorkflow.PrmConfiguration.DownKey}"
                        ParameterizedCommand="{Binding SwitchCommand}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding KioskWorkflow.PrmConfiguration.DownKey}" />
                    <behaviors:KeyElement
                        Key="{Binding KioskWorkflow.PrmConfiguration.EnterKey}"
                        Command="{Binding SubmitCommand}" />
                </behaviors:WindowKeyPressBehavior.KeyCommandCollection>
            </behaviors:WindowKeyPressBehavior>
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <Grid></Grid>
    </UserControl>
```

### **The Problem I have**

I am able to run the application properly and everything seems to be working. The only reason I am unhappy is that I don't want the `KeyElement` to be a `FrameworkElement`. Instead I want it to be a plain `DependencyObject`. Problem I am facing with this being a `Dependency Object` is that I don't get the `DataContext` property because of which I am not able to set the Binding properly in Code.
Also I don't want to call the `LoadDataContexts` method in the behavior.

I tried using the `BindingProxy` approach but I don't like that approach as well as it needs me to declare a static resource in every page.

I have tried making the class `KeyElement` inherit from `Freezable` but that is not helping me either, as Binding is not happening, and even though it is freezable, it is not inheriting the `DataContext` from the parent i.e. the Behavior/UserControl. Tried several options by using `RelativeSource` but the `DataContext` is always null.

Also I get the below error in Output if I replace the FrameworkElement with Freezable:-

```bat
    System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element
```

I had a look at the `KeyBinding` class and it does not inherit from FrameworkElement still does not throw any error in output window.
Any way of achieving the behavior without using a `FrameworkElement` ?
Any suggestions on improving the above code is also welcome.

Comment: Why don't you use [`UIElement.InputBindings`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.inputbindings?view=netcore-3.1#examples)? It does exactly what you are trying to implement. Regarding the `DataContext`, you can always use `Binding.RelativeSource` to do visual tree traversal to find the `DataContext` youo need.

Comment: The UIElement.InputBindings has not been used as with the InputBindings, I need to propagate the bindings to the Window element, which is a problem in my case. I have other focussed elements in my Page which take away the KeyUp events.

Comment: I tried RelativeSource FindAncestor, but it is not working.

Comment: You can define input bindings on any `UIElement` not only `Window`. Only the example uses a `Window` to bind to key events.

Comment: It can, but for that the UIElement needs to be focussed, which is not in my case.

Comment: @undefined: A `FrameworkElement` *is* a `DependencyObject`. Could you please clarify what your issue really is here?

Comment: @mm8, the problem is when I am making `KeyElement` as `Freezable`, I am not able to Bind the commands as I am not getting the `DataContext` using `RelativeSource `or even with `ElementName`. 

I am not willing to use a `FrameworkElement` in the behavior as I somehow feel it is not right and instead using `Freezable` like Microsoft's `KeyBinding`, but I am not able to get it working.

Also, when I replace the `FrameworkElement` with a `Freezable`, I get errors in the Output Window

`Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element`